# Swiffy flash to html5 conversion keeps looping

Tags: html, flash, loops

A friend has an older website with a flash front end.  He would like to replace it with something more modern and mobile friendly, but doesn't have the original Flash files.

I used Swiffy to convert it to HTML5 and was able to embed it easily enough.  You can see the results on this test page:  http://www.houldsworth.us/mb-test-3/

However, as you can see, it keeps looping and we really need to it play just once and stop.

Anyone know a fix that can cure this?  I've searched several places and found nothing.

TIA!

Comment: The link is not working ("server not found"). If you had the FLA files, you could add a STOP action at the end before exporting to swiffy. If there's not one in the SWF (assuming that's what you converted to html5) not much you can do. ...except maybe export a simple FLA with a stop action on the timeline, then open the html file and figure out which bit of code says "stop".

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  
Yes, I exported from the SWF but that one stops after one iteration.  
Not sure why you were getting server not found - it works fine for me even in incognito and from a different ISP.

Comment: I just tried with an iPad and yes everything loaded. But on a Windows PC I get "Server not found" (FF) and "Unable to resolve the server's DNS address" (Chrome) for http://houldsworth.us/flash5home.html which seems to be a frame in the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the HTML file `flash5home.html` in Textpad or something similar. Find the following code, which is almost at the end of the file:

```
{"type":2}],"fileSize":
```

Change that to:

```
{"type":9,"actions":[{"type":7}]},{"type":2}],"fileSize":
```

...and it should stop. I can't test it because I can't view or copy your source in iPad.

Comment: Thanks. If you "accept the answer", then I get my first ever "correct answer" award.

Comment: I didn't see the checkmark before.  Done now :)  Thanks again.

Comment: It works fine :)  But can you explain how it works ? Then it would better for others who are facing the same problem. @plugincontainer

Comment: To find the answer, I made 2 very simple almost identical swfs - one with a "stop" action at the end and one without. Then I exported them as swiffy files, Then I compared the code of the two swiffy files (in textpad) to find the extra bit of code in the swiffy-with-a-stop.file (which was {"type":9,"actions":[{"type":7}]},). But I don't know how it works.

Comment: Thanks.  I have this working now.  I modified the fixed width of the container from 640px to 100% and the height is set to 400px. That works fine, only problem now is that when it displays on a phone there is a huge amount of space above and below it.  If I change height to 100% it does this weird growing effect and keeps resizing as you scroll around the page.  Any thoughts on how to have the height relative to the width without that happening?

Comment: Haven't used swiffy in ages, but - can you post a link?